# How to make a “reflective tape” material in cycles? Nodes Question

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, workflow, shaders

Question to original link: [How to make a "reflective tape" material in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69590/how-to-make-a-reflective-tape-material-in-cycles/82588?noredirect=1#comment145760_82588)

I'm using Blender 2.78c, any ideas on making too. Nodes look different.
I am trying make my signs Retroreflective for Farming Simulator 17.

[image: MUTCD R1-1 or Stop Sign]

Comment: None of the used nodes have changed. They all are still there, and named the same.

Comment: first off as I said in my first comment. "None of the used nodes have changed. They all are still there, and named the same." Make sure you really are using cycles. 2 Even if you get your cycles material set up as in the [answers to my question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/69590/2217) it will not work in farm simulator. You will have to find out what farm sim is made it, what its game engine expects for materials, and then if you can even fake retroreflectiveity with just a material and some textures (I doubt it).

Answer (score 4):

I just remade this material in 2.78 and it functions the same.

[image: Material]

You seem to be new to Blender. I would suggest checking that you are using the cycles render and are in the material tab (not the compositing tab).

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. To my mind your answer is fine - validating that it still works the same at 2.78 and even offering a suggestion as to where the questioner might have gone wrong. Gets my up vote

Comment: @RichSedman Thanks I was wondering the same thing.

Comment: (To remove any doubt) I did not vote either way on this post. But after coming back to the two answers, I have UVed yours.

Answer (score -1):

This would be my suggestion on how to make this kind of material using a texture.
The first node tier is defining the texture with transparency as the reflective material using Fresnel (Fresnel defines the glossy to be applied only almost face on), the second mix node just mixes it with a diffuse background (or anything else) using the alpha channel as the factor.

[image]

For added realism i would probably use a hexagon texture to simulate the granularity of such a reflective tape at a close up, like here:

[image]

Comment: I fail to see in your nodes where you make the actual retroreflective part. From your nodes all you made is a material that is using an image to define what part is glossy, and the glossy is just a standard glossy node. If you lok at the [answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/69595/2217) you will see that you need to modify the normal of the glossy node to create the retroreflective property.

Comment: No you really dont, as the fresnel node controls that property much more accurately and gives you much more control over it.
You can achieve the same result with using the Layer Weight node, using the Facing connector.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question correctly.
The reflective tape pictured i added as an example is what i used as the baseline for my answer, maybe some other reflective tape needs a different approach, but that was not clear from the question.

Comment: David, how can I combine your work plus an image of a stop sign? I have a stop sign image with the hexagon texture added.