# Security Hologram Sticker

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders

I'd like to know how to create a holographic material using nodes/texture maps to replicate a security hologram like this:

[image: Security Hologram]

[image: Security Hologram]

I cannot seem to find any information regarding this anywhere. I have tried myself numerous times to replicate this effect using gradient/metallic nodes and texture maps to make the reflection look convincing but I cannot seem to get a good result. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: One related thread about the reflective material: [How to make a “reflective tape” material in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/69590/78972)

Comment: One regarding the iridescent colors:[Iridescence in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1605/78972)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make a shiny, iridescent material, it is very simple.  All you need to do is follow my node setup, which I have provided below:[image]
once that is done, you should have a very iridescent material (see image below).
[image]
If you want  to make a security hologram-like sticker in your question, you can simply texture paint an image of a sticker onto a mesh, then add a mix shader and mix your iridescent shader with the image texture (see image below)
[image]
hope this helped!  If you encounter further problems, let me know and I'll be happy to help. : )

(PS, you might need to enlarge the images to see the node setup.   sorry about how small they are)