# Add sharp noise to material

Tags: materials

Hello I´m trying to add noise to a material with eevee and this is what I achieved:

[image: too soft]

The problem is that the noise is too soft and I can't find a way to sharpen it.

Here's an example of what I want, I made it with Cycles some time ago:

[image: Sharp noise]

It should look a bit like glitter and use eevee

Comment: For your-actual-glitter, you might want to check [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/105302/35559)

Comment: The best way to "sharpen" noise is piping it through a Color Ramp. Where you can focus the values and change the gradient type i.e. linear, ease, constant etc